# HWIOAuthBundle - Symfony2 - Get User Data from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

How i can get the correct User Data from Facebook Connect like a Profile Picture (Currently return null), First Name and Last Name (Seems that now is implent only Full name)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In overall it's quite easy and requires just some adjustments in `config.yml`:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name:         secured_area
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:          facebook
            client_id:     <client_id>
            client_secret: <client_secret>
            infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=username,name,picture.type(square)"
            paths:
                profilepicture: picture.data.url
```

More details can be found in [documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/internals/response_object_and_paths.md).

Comment: and how to access the data (picture) in the code? (for example in the controller)

Comment: okay, I got it. I have to make something like this: `$this->getResourceOwnerByName('facebook')->getUserInformation($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getRawToken())->getResponse()`

Comment: @pleerock You use the path name: $response->getProfilePicture();

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggest, but how do I pick up the user's email? Thank you

Comment: what can I do to get Birth Date Information. nothing is added in documentation